# Need help using manual legends in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to add legends to my R ggplot2 graphs, but clearly I'm not getting the syntax right.

```
# basic plot layout
ggplot() + 
     labs(x="random values", y="frequency", title="Examples for F-Test") +
     theme_minimal() +

# histogram of distributions
     geom_histogram(data=data.frame(random.data.1), aes(x=random.data.1), fill="forestgreen", color="grey", alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.5) +
     geom_histogram(data=data.frame(random.data.2), aes(x=random.data.2), fill="orange", color="black", alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.5) +
 
# manual text annotations  
     annotate("text", x=10, y=5, label=paste("F-Test p-value =", signif(F.test[[3]], digits=3)), color="firebrick", fontface="bold") +

# add legend?
    scale_color_manual(name="Distributions", values=c("grey", "black"))
```

Comment: Since you are a new member: try to give minimal, reproducible examples whenever possible.  In this case, you could give a toy dataset and eliminate some of the extra junk - check out the excellent guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks fir the pointer. I’ll pay attention to it next time around.

Comment: Thanks Mario.  If my answer worked for you, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkmark under the up/down vote arrows.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, John. That worked and thank you for the pointers about how to work properly with data frames and ggplot. I hope that as I progress beyond the first few days of working with R things get a bit more intuitive. 

Only minor point is that in one line there's a '1' missing
df$dset <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)) #Indicates the dataset

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mario -- I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot2 usually works better if you concatenate your data into long-form columns, as I've done here, with one or more additional columns that indicate the variables or datasets that you want to use to group formatting options.  In this case, since you wanted to split by dataset, I just used "1" and "2" for the fake datasets.  That column should be a factor (if it's not, then R will assume that the variable is continuous).  The command you are specifically looking for is `guides()`, I think.

Reshaping data can be done easily with either the "reshape2" package or the "tidyr" package.  [This post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/how-to-reshape-data-in-r-tidyr-vs-reshape2/) compares them.

```r
library(ggplot2)
random.data.1 = runif(10)
random.data.2 = runif(10)
df = data.frame(vals = c(random.data.1,random.data.2))
df$dset<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)) #Indicates the dataset
df$dset<-factor(df$dset)
df

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=vals,color=dset,fill=dset,group=dset)) + 
  labs(x="random values", y="frequency", title="Examples for F-Test") +
  #theme_minimal() +
  
  # histogram of distributions (now you only need one line!)
  geom_histogram(position="stack",alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.5) +
  
  # manual text annotations  
  annotate("text", x=10, y=5, label=paste("F-Test p-value =", signif(F.test[[3]], digits=3)), color="firebrick", fontface="bold") +
  
  # add legend?
  #These lines set the colors
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey", "black"))  + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("forest green","orange")) + 

  #and these set the legend manually
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Distributions")) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) #don't show the fill legend
```